# Unable to register avro schema

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

Can only seem to create schema from local ide pointing towards dev schema reg and brokers. A deployed application running from an EC2 will send the message and not show errors but i can not view he schema in the reg when i hit the endpoint https://{{ schemaRegistry }}:8081/subjects/

**Update**

Since progressed, and no answers yet. It seems the logs do not recognise any request from the deployed application to register a schema, when I tail them and send a message there is nothing in the schema registry logs. It definitely has the correct broker and schema registry configured in the application. There is no error in the logs now since i removed the zookeepers which i have figured out from the documentation that I do not need.

Comment: Please add server logs to the question

Comment: Updated the question as have progessed a little @cricket_007

Comment: Added a bounty @cricket_007, let me know any other info needed

Comment: How many Schema Registry do you have? Are they using separate Kafka clusters?

Comment: I should only have 1, i know this looks like i have another running. I was switching from one cluster onto another

Comment: Again, edit the question to include the logs. You may not see anything, but we might. Also add your server.properties and schema-registry.properties. Show your VPC settings

Comment: Why don't you use something like this ? https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/confluent-platform/ Are you using MSK? Are you using EKS? Do you post issues to Github? https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/issues/

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007 I will be back at this Monday and update the info